# Parse Node to FXML

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, fxml, java-io

Can´t find any questions about this, so I ask: **Is there a way in Java (Eclipse IDE) to parse a JavaFX Node to a FXML String so I can save it to a file?** Thanks for your answers in advance.

```
//Something like this:
VBox main = new VBox();
String fxml = main.toFXML();
```

Comment: No, there isn't. But defining Java objects as FXML is not a difficult process. I imagine a library could be written to do this, though I don't see a point to it, honestly.

Comment: Yes, it's not technically difficult to write a FXML serializer, but it's definitely a lot of hard work. You need to find every single `Node` (though you can look at the list in SceneBuilder), find out every single configurable property (you need to filter out layout properties like `widthProperty()` and `layoutBoundsProperty()` etc), then call the getters of those properties to get their values, then represent them in the FXML format.

Comment: You could study the [source code of _Scene Builder_](https://github.com/gluonhq/scenebuilder) for inspiration. At some point _Scene Builder_ must translate the `Node`s you put on the screen to FXML otherwise the app wouldn't work but I don't know where in the code this occurs, unfortunately. But keep in mind, as those above me have mentioned this is no easy undertaking and has little use cases. If you're trying to persist UI state you should instead be persisting the model and rebuild the UI from there.

Comment: I would recommend rebuilding your node with scene builder it really shouldn't take that long unless the project it absolutely massive